# OAuth Test Console signature doesn't agree with working request

Tags: c#, oauth, linkedin-api

I'm having trouble using the LinkedIn API due to being returned a 401 with `auth_problem=signature_invalid`. I do however have a project which seems to be working with fine so I'm using this to identify the differences.

I read that I can debug with the [OAuthTestConsole](https://developer.linkedin.com/oauth-test-console) however this appears to be **generating a different signature** than the *working* project.

Since I'm this is only a hobby you can have both my keys:

```
API Key: gh69xphn2hcr
Secret Key: 0ld6NVvjmpvrmZqw
```

My working request is:

```
POST https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Host: api.linkedin.com
Content-Length: 175
Connection: Keep-Alive

oauth_consumer_key=gh69xphn2hcr&oauth_nonce=186481&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1325243837&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=gTeEgzknW6DyI3aFTDcXduroIG4%3d
```

However the [oAuthTestConsole](https://developer.linkedin.com/oauth-test-console) returns an oauth_signature of `WNcZFXAC5Y2hoK4srFiFc69zi0M=` which is nothing alike (encoded or not).

I'm thinking I must be using the TestConsole wrong and this is preventing me from fixing my issue between the working / non working projects. Could you please point me in the right direction as to why this might occur?

Answer (score 0):

To use the OAuth Test Console, you need to make sure that all of the parameters are exactly the same 
- the timestamp (you'll need to set that manually, as it'll otherwise be created based on the current time)
- the nonce (check to see what your library is sending)
- the method (POST in this case)

You need to clear both fields for the access_token (since you don't have one for this initial request)

There is a working C# example posted by a community member here:
https://developer.linkedin.com/thread/1190

Many people have had a lot of luck starting with that, as using OAuth can be tricky without an example to start from.